# Library only seemingly partly included, C and Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

I'm using `pthread.h` and `semaphore.h` in my program, and have included those libraries. However, it seems that although I can call some thread functions (such as `pthread_exit()`) and create semaphore variables, I can't use other functions such as`sem_wait`. I get an `undefined reference` complaint from Eclipse. Any idea why this is happening? In the code below, the `semaphore.h` functions in `void *thread1(void* v)` don't work. The error log is below the code.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef long long ll;
sem_t mutex;
int num=0;

void A(void);

void handler(void *ptr)
{
    pthread_exit(0);
}

double calculateAverage(double *arr, int len)
{
    double average=0.00;
    //first sum up all entries
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        average+=arr[i];
    }
    return average;
}

static inline ll timespec_to_ns(const struct timespec *tv)
{
    return ((ll) tv->tv_sec * 1000000000) + tv->tv_nsec;
}
ll beginMeasureTime() {
    struct timespec t;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t);
    return timespec_to_ns(&t);
}
ll endMeasureTime(ll beginTime) {
    struct timespec t;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t);
    return timespec_to_ns(&t)-beginTime;
}

ll measureFunctionCall(int n) {
    ll beginTime=beginMeasureTime();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        A();
    }
    return endMeasureTime(beginTime);
}
ll measureSyscall(int n) {
    ll beginTime=beginMeasureTime();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        syscall(SYS_getpid);
    }
    return endMeasureTime(beginTime);
}
ll measureProcessSwitch(int n) {
    int p[2];
    int p1[2];
    char arr;
    ll t=-1;
    // 0 for read 1 for writing
    if(pipe(p)<0) {
        perror("pipe");
        return -1;
    }
    if(pipe(p1)<0) {
        perror("pipe");
        goto out1;
    }
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid<0) {
        perror("fork");
        goto out2;
    }
    if(pid==0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            if(read(p[0],&arr,1)<=0) _exit(1);
            if(write(p1[1],&arr,1)<=0) _exit(1);
        }
        _exit(0);
    }
    ll beginTime=beginMeasureTime();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(write(p[1],&arr,1)<=0) {
            perror("write");
            goto out2;
        }
        if(read(p1[0],&arr,1)<=0) {
            perror("read");
            goto out2;
        }
    }
    t=endMeasureTime(beginTime);
out2:
    close(p1[0]);
    close(p1[1]);
out1:
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    return t;
}

typedef struct {
    sem_t s1;   //parent->child
    sem_t s2;   //child->parent
    int abort;
} info;

void* thread1(void* v) {
    info* inf=(info*)v;
    while(1)
    {
        if( sem_wait(&inf->s1) < 0) break;
        if(inf->abort) break;
        sem_post(&inf->s2);
    }
    return NULL;
}
ll measureThreadSwitch(int n) {
    info inf;
    inf.abort=0;
    ll t=-1;
    // 0 for read 1 for writing
    if(sem_init(&inf.s1,0,0)<0) {
        perror("sem_init");
        return -1;
    }
    if(sem_init(&inf.s2,0,0)<0) {
        perror("sem_init");
        goto out1;
    }
    pthread_t th;
    if(pthread_create(&th,NULL,&thread1,&inf)<0) {
        perror("pthread_create");
        goto out2;
    }

    ll beginTime=beginMeasureTime();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(sem_post(&inf.s1)<0) {
            perror("sem_post");
            goto out3;
        }
        if(sem_wait(&inf.s2)<0)  {
            perror("sem_wait");
            goto out3;
        }
    }
    t=endMeasureTime(beginTime);
out3:
    //thread is still running; need to signal to it to exit
    //and wait for it to exit
    inf.abort=1;
    sem_post(&inf.s1);
    pthread_join(th,NULL);
out2:
    sem_destroy(&inf.s2);
out1:
    sem_destroy(&inf.s1);
    return t;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc <2)
    {
        printf("You entered less than two arguements\n");
        exit(-2);
    }
    if(argv[1] <0)
    {
        printf("you entered a negative argument\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    int n=(atoi(argv[1]));

    printf("function call: %lld ns\n",measureFunctionCall(n)/n);
    printf("system call: %lld ns\n",measureSyscall(n)/n);
    printf("process switching: %lld ns\n",measureProcessSwitch(n)/n);
    printf("thread switching: %lld ns\n",measureThreadSwitch(n)/n);
}
```

`/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:123: undefined reference to`sem_wait'
/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:125: undefined reference to `sem_post'
./src/test.o: In function`measureThreadSwitch':
/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:134: undefined reference to `sem_init'
/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:138: undefined reference to`sem_init'
/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:143: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:150: undefined reference to`sem_post'
/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:154: undefined reference to `sem_wait'
/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:164: undefined reference to`sem_post'
/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:165: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:167: undefined reference to`sem_destroy'
/home/anb1/workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.c:169: undefined reference to `sem_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1`

Comment: There is a differences between header files/compilation and libraries/linking. You apparently messed up the latter.

Comment: You need to tell us what the link flags are. In particular, are you including `-pthread` in the build?

Comment: That was the problem, forgot that linker flag. If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made your program compile by including correct header files, but you must make it link correctly. Visit https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/332260/ as it reflects what you have to do in Eclipse. The thing you must include is `pthread` library.